# When importing a component from my own library it gives me the type "any"

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm having a problem when importing a component from my own library.

The component inside the library, is actually a component from another one (so I'm importing the component, customizing it and then exporting the custom).

But when I import my own library on an application, the component loses the original type that come from the original library, so if you see the image here, it says that I'm geting `any` even though I'm exporting it:

[image: When importing]

And this is how it is inside the library exported types:

[image: The exported types]

It shows the actual type that I should be receiving it.

Comment: Weird, could u show the code in codesandbox?

Comment: @zixiCat After a couple hours of investigation I found out that it was VSCode fault. I did a full refresh and it indexed all over again and the type was corrected.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hours of investigation I found out that it was VSCode fault. I did a full refresh and it indexed all over again and the type was corrected.